# How to pause VLC from the command line

Tags: vlc, dbus, i3

I use i3wm as my window manager and I want to add a binding to play/pause, next, prev and stop VLC. However, unlike MPV, VLC doesn't have built-in CLI control when the VLC process is already running externally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would installing `playerctl` work, alternatively?

Comment: This is even better than my solution ! Playerctl is labelled as *"For players supporting the MPRIS D-Bus specification"*, which includes Spotify and VLC afaik. It works flawlessly and if far less barbaric than `dbus-send` lol. Though looking at the dbus syntax, playerctl is essetially doing the same thing as what I did. I will use playerctl instead, thank you :D

Comment: ``playerctl`` seems to be a fine tool, however it's not available on Windows. Is there an alternative for this OS?

Answer (score 7):

I found [this lovely Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/ahmi28/is_it_possible_to_pause_vlc_from_the_command_line/eefxg7j?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) answering than need for play/pause, and through trial and error I found how to also stop/prev and next:

```
bindsym XF86AudioNext exec dbus-send --type=method_call \
        --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc \
        /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Next

bindsym XF86AudioPrev exec dbus-send --type=method_call \
        --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc \
        /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Previous

bindsym XF86AudioPlay exec dbus-send --type=method_call \
        --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc \
        /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause

bindsym XF86AudioStop exec dbus-send --type=method_call \
        --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc \
        /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Stop
```

EDIT: Using `playerctl` like Antoine mentionned makes this more straightforward:

```
bindsym XF86AudioNext exec playerctl next

bindsym XF86AudioPrev exec playerctl previous

bindsym XF86AudioPlay exec playerctl play

bindsym XF86AudioStop exec playerctl pause
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using playerctl for controlling any playback settings

```
# Media player controls
bindsym XF86AudioPlay exec playerctl play-pause
#bindsym XF86AudioPause exec playerctl pause
bindsym XF86AudioNext exec playerctl next
bindsym XF86AudioPrev exec playerctl previous
```

But, if two applications are using audio at the same time, which one will respond to `playerctl`, is unknown.